# People picker functional in Sharepoint 2013. How to use check names?

Tags: people-picker, people-search

Been playing around with some Sharepoint 2013 stuff. 
Made my custom form to user can fill some credentials.

My problem is that I want to use that `CheckNames` thing functional on my client side.

This is form part which handles stuff

```
 <td style="width:90%;" valign="top">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div autopostback="0" class="ms-inputuserfield" id="UserField_checkNames_upLevelDiv" name="upLevelDiv" 
                         style="display: none; position: absolute; height: 20px;" tabindex="0"></div>
                    <textarea autopostback="0" class="ms-input" cols="20" id="UserField_checkNames_downlevelTextBox" 
                              rows="1" style="width: 100%; height: 18px;" title="People Picker"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
<td id="spExtrasHolder" align="right" nowrap="true" style="padding-left:5px;" valign="top">
    <a href="javascript:" id="UserField_checkNames" onclick="ShPointStuff.overridenCheckNames(this);" title="Check Names">
    <img alt="Check Names" src="/_layouts/images/checknames.gif" style="border-width:0px;" title="Check Names"></a>
</td>
```

I tried to do something like that, with my custom callback functions but it looks like it not goes there

```
// Overriden function for name checking
instance.overridenCheckNames = function (element) {
    var me = this,
        id = element.id;

    if (!ValidatePickerControl(id)) { ShowValidationError(); return false; }

    var arg = getUplevel(id),
        ctx = id;

    EntityEditorSetWaitCursor(ctx);
    WebForm_DoCallback(id, arg, me.overrideCheckNamesResultHandller, ctx, me.overrideCheckNamesErrorHandller, true);
};
```

It gets my input element inner data, also takes the element  id and goes to `WebForm_DoCallback` with it but nothing happens after!

No error, no success.

I got other test site, and when I debugging it - it gets same stuff but successfully returns something.

[image]

I bet this guids makes sense, but don't know what excatly.

Also, I got no access to server side, only can write some custom js stuff.

So, is there are way to toggle `checknames` for my custom form from my custom function?

P.S.

above is copied from SO.

**UPD:**

Found this article here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1008871/Developing-Custom-Date-Picker-People-Picker-and-Ch

Tried approach with `POST`request.

But response I got is

> value=A null value was found with the expected type
>   'Edm.Int32[Nullable=False]'. The expected type
>   'Edm.Int32[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.

Request screenshot from fiddler:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Interesing, but it works this way!
Wondering why it's not allow me make custom `POST` request.

When I look at the fields in `query` variable, I saw that it has wierd field names, maybe that's the reason!

So, one of the way to toggle custom name checking is this:

```
instance.overridenCheckNames = function (element) {
    var me = this,
        id = element.id;

    if (!ValidatePickerControl(id)) { ShowValidationError(); return false; }

    var arg = getUplevel(id),
        ctx = id,
        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
        query = new SP.UI.ApplicationPages.ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters();

    query.set_allowMultipleEntities(false);
    query.set_maximumEntitySuggestions(50);
    query.set_principalType(1);
    query.set_principalSource(15);
    query.set_queryString(arg);

    var searchResult = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.clientPeoplePickerSearchUser(clientContext, query);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        var results = clientContext.parseObjectFromJsonString(searchResult.get_value());
        var txtResults = '';
    });
};
```